# Take backup of a server which is 90% full

Tags: mysql, backup, rsync, tar, copy

How to take backup of a live (database) ubuntu server, which is 90% full and also
How to use tar or rsync & mysqldump command to copy from one server to another?

Comment: Backup to where? And why can't you use `tar`?

Comment: i mean how to do it in remotely

Comment: Have you looked into using `rsync`?

Comment: mysql replication is another option if all you need is the mysql data http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

From any machine that can access this server across a network on TCP port 3306, you can use `mysqldump` remotely, and it's exactly the same as running it on the server itself, except the dump file will be created locally.

The `--host` option is used to specify the IP address of the server.  The `--compress` option will usually allow the transfer to be faster across the wire.  That is its purpose -- transport compression -- it doesn't make the actual backup file smaller.

This can be done with the server running normally.

`rsync` is not a safe tool to use to back up a MySQL server, if MySQL is running.  It won't actually hurt the server, and the backup will appear to work, but the files will not be usable.  The same applies for `tar` or any other to that copies the files themselves.  Using `mysqldump` does not read the files directly, even if run locally.

In Ubuntu, typing `mysqldump` on a machine where it isn't installed, should prompt you with several options of "client" packages that include it, any one of which should be fine.